Firebase Firestore Swift - Pagination navigation backwards shows wrong items
I'm implementing pagination in my iOS Swift app with Firebase Firestore, and I'm having issues with backwards navigation. When clicking the "previous page" button, it shows newer items instead of older ones.
Here's my current implementation:
func loadNextPage() {
    guard let lastDocument = lastDocument else { return }
    
    isLoading = true
    currentPage += 1
    
    var query = db.collection("items")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .start(afterDocument: lastDocument)
        .limit(to: itemsPerPage)
    
    // Apply filters...
    
    query.getDocuments { [weak self] snapshot, error in
        // Handle results...
        self.items = snapshot.documents.compactMap { self.documentToItem($0) }
        self.lastDocument = snapshot.documents.last
    }
}

func loadPreviousPage() {
    guard !isLoading else { return }
    
    isLoading = true
    currentPage -= 1
    
    var query = db.collection("items")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
    
    if let firstItem = items.first {
        query = query.whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: firstItem.timestamp)
            .limit(to: itemsPerPage)
    }
    
    // Apply filters...
    
    query.getDocuments { [weak self] snapshot, error in
        // Handle results...
        self.items = snapshot.documents.compactMap { self.documentToItem($0) }
        self.lastDocument = snapshot.documents.last
    }
}

What I've tried so far:

Using start(after:) with the first item's timestamp:
swift
query = query.start(after: [firstItem.timestamp])


Using end(before:) with the first item's timestamp:
query = query.end(before: [firstItem.timestamp])


Changing the order direction for previous page:
query = db.collection("items")
  .order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)


Using whereField with different comparisons:
swift
query = query.whereField("timestamp", isLessThan: firstItem.timestamp)



The pagination works perfectly when going forward, but when trying to go backwards:

Sometimes it shows the same items as the next page
Sometimes it jumps to the first page
Sometimes it shows newer items instead of older ones

My data structure in Firestore:
Collection with documents
Each document has a timestamp field (server timestamp)
Using descending order by timestamp
Limiting to N items per page

How can I implement proper backwards pagination that shows the previous N items chronologically?

First off: consider passing in firstItem rather than firstItem.timestamp, so that Firestore has more information to work with (especially in case of multiple items with the same timestamp).

Thanks, I changed that, but still its not possible. The only way I could manage that was to change the sort order and then navigate forwards, which mixes up the order of the items. There must be a better was as its such a basic task. Any Ideas?

That used to be the only way to do this in the initial API, but the endAt/endBefore API should make that workaround unnecessary. I'm not sure why it's not working for you here, so I hope somebody else spots it and answers.
